# Tomcat logging in eclipse

Tags: eclipse, logging, tomcat6

I would like to see the output of my log in Eclipse Console.
I had configured it a while ago and do not seem to recollect.

I have the log4j.properties file.

I am not sure of the right place to place it so that the output is displayed in Eclipse console instead of being written to a file in tomcat\logs.
I am using tomcat 6.0.24

Please help.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the Eclipse WTP project to run servers and have their console output displayed in Eclipse. See the [WTP Tomcat FAQ](http://wiki.eclipse.org/WTP_Tomcat_FAQ) for details.

Also, make sure you're using a [ConsoleAppender](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/manual.html) in your log4j.properties configuration.

Comment: Figured it out. I placed the log4j.properties file in tomcat\lib. Many Thanks.